# Elasticsearch script - variable not defined

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm following an Elasticsearch [tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/partial-updates.html), but ran into a problem when trying to use parameters in a script.

**Step 1: Create a new document - OK** (`index = website; type = blog; id = 1`)

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/website/blog/1?pretty -d '{
  "title":"my first post",
  "tags" : [ "tag1" ]
}'
```

**Step 2: Use script to append an extra value to `tags` array - ERROR**

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/website/blog/1/_update?pretty -d '{
   "script" : "ctx._source.tags+=new_tag",
   "params" : {
      "new_tag" : "tag2"
   }
}'
```

The error message is this, mentioning `"reason" : "Variable [new_tag] is not defined."` But I have defined the variable `new_tag` as described on the tutorial page. What am I doing wrong?

```
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason" : "[mrukUvA][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to execute script",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "script_exception",
      "reason" : "compile error",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Variable [new_tag] is not defined."
      },
      "script_stack" : [
        "ctx._source.tags+=new_tag",
        "                  ^---- HERE"
      ],
      "script" : "ctx._source.tags+=new_tag",
      "lang" : "painless"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

**Step 2 (retry) Qualifying `new_tag` with `params` - ERROR**

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/website/blog/1/_update?pretty -d '{
   "script" : {
       "inline": "ctx._source.tags+=params.new_tag",
       "params" : {
          "new_tag" : "tag2"
       }
   }
}'
```

Gives error

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason" : "[mrukUvA][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to execute script",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "script_exception",
      "reason" : "runtime error",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "class_cast_exception",
        "reason" : "Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.util.ArrayList"
      },
      "script_stack" : [
        "ctx._source.tags+=params.new_tag",
        "                        ^---- HERE"
      ],
      "script" : "ctx._source.tags+=params.new_tag",
      "lang" : "painless"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

**As a sanity check to make sure the document is valid**

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:9200/website/blog/1?pretty
{
  "_index" : "website",
  "_type" : "blog",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 27,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "title" : "my first post",
    "tags" : [
      "tag1"
    ]
  }
}
```

So the document does have the valid field `tag` which is an array.

Comment: You may need to access the variable with params.new_tag. You need to state that it comes from the params.

Comment: Thanks @christinabo I tried that, but doing so gives a different error `caused_by: type: script_exception", reason:"runtime error", "null_pointer_exception"`  Looks like this arises from trying to dereference `params`. I'm guessing the tutorial suggests `params` has special meaning here.

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: @Val I am using 5.2.2

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off, if you have parameters you need to `inline` the script. Try this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/website/blog/1/_update?pretty -d '{
   "script" : {
       "inline": "ctx._source.tags.add(params.new_tag)",
       "params" : {
          "new_tag" : "tag2"
       }
   }
}'
```

Comment: Hi @Val, seems it still gets the same error :-( I updated my question to include this attempt.

Comment: My bad, you need to prefix `new_tag` with `params`

Comment: Interesting, this time I'm getting `"Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.util.ArrayList"`, I guess now the script syntax needs to be fixed somehow!

Comment: painless is no groovy (the `+=` operator in groovy needs to be changed to a method call to the `add` method) :-) See my updated answer

Comment: I see! This worked - `"result" : "updated"` Thank you very much @Val!

Answer (score 5):

you can use "inline" although it is deprecated. now you alse can use "source" to replace "inline" for no warnings. for example:

```html
"script" : {
     "source": "ctx._source.tags.add(params.new_tag)",
     "params": {
       "new_tag":"tag1"
     }
   }
```